# Error: Unable to detect the web framework in use, check firebase-debug.log for more info

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting

I encounter this error when I tried to a flutter website with firebase hosting. This is my commands that I executed in the root directory of the flutter project:

```
flutter build web
```

Then I add the `script tag` to the `build/web/index.html` as instructed

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

```
firebase login
```

```
firebase init //or// firebase init hosting
```

(doesn't matter with the first option you just have to specify in the options then)

```
*Then I change the "source" in the firebase.json file:*
 "hosting": {
    "source": "build/web",
    "ignore": [...
```

```
firebase deploy
```

After I run `firebase deploy` I get the error:

> Error: Unable to detect the web framework in use, check firebase-debug.log for more info.

The only solution I have read is to downgrade firebase but when I downgraded from `13.0.2` to `12.4.0` (recommended after encountering this error) nothing happens I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I re-config Flutter Web, following the steps in this official given link https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/flutter

and it worked fine for me!

Note: Also before proceeding with the above step make sure to re-auth your firebase, you can do that using the below command
`firebase login --reauth`

or you can try re-login as well

```bash
$ firebase logout
$ firebase login
```